# Using FetchType.LAZY with JBoss/Wildfly and JSON

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jax-rs, wildfly

In WildFly, I defined an entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Table("OrderTable")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class OrderEntity {
    private List<ItemEntity> items;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = ItemEntity.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="ITEM_ID")
    public List<ItemEntity> getItems() {...}
    public void setItems(List<ItemEntity> items) {...}
}
```

Then using JaxRS, I defined this to retrieve the data

```
    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
   public Response getOrder(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        OrderEntity order= orderService.retrieveOrder(id);
        return Response.ok(order).build()
   }
```

My issue is while the orderService business layer have no problem returning the order entity, when I attempt to return the Response.ok(), mapping to JSON, it would complain my items are not loaded: "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role"

Does this mean I MUST load all the relations in order to make this work, even if I do not need to access the items relations?

Comment: What version of WildFly are you using?

Comment: version 30.0.0-Final

Answer (score 0):

JSON doesn't know what do you need if you didn't say that explicitly.

The ways to solve that:

1. Add `@JsonIgnore` to `getItems` if you don't need them.
2. Add `cascade=EAGER` to load items if you do need them.
3. Add `@Transaction` to `getOrder` method to load items (this way is not recommended, but technically it helps).
4. Add some intermediate DTO layer - in this case you can have several DTOs for one entity for different cases, they will have a different set of fields depending on what you need.
5. The way that also allows to load different data sets but without DTO - [JPA Entity Graph](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph).

Comment: Solution 1 won't work as I think it drops the items ALL the time.
Solution 2 I think is the fetch=FetchType.EAGER, which is what I do now
Solution 3 is also used, but I need to access the items list inside the transaction. That's possible and my service layer is transactional, as it also need to do other things
4 is possible, may be what I need to do
5 is where I get issue if I don't use the graph to load everything. I get the entity fine, but the Response() fails 'cause I think it tries to access the items that I don't have loaded.
Thx!